# Exchange 2003 to 2010 public folder replication

Tags: exchange, replication, directory

I've found several guides and tutorials on public folder replication from 2003 to 2010, but am still a little bit confused.

What we have, is a 2003 exchange server obviously holding all of our public folders, and two 2010 exchange servers in a DAG, that we want to move the public folders to.

On each of the exchange 2010 servers, we have run AddReplicaToPFRecursive.ps1 script and then update-publicfolderhierarchy script.

I can see that the data base has grown in size, although it is now double the size of the database on 2003. If I run get-publicfolderstatistics then it lists all of the public folders, and I can see they have items in them, and they have appropriate sizes.

However. If I open the public folder management console on a 2010 server, then I can see the folder hierarchy, but non of the folders actually show any items in them.

Is there something else I have to do before moving all replicas to 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However. If I open the public folder management console on a 2010 server, then I can see the folder hierarchy, but non of the folders actually show any items in them.

> PFMC is not supposed to list out the contents of the Public Folder. It just displays the top level hierarchy.
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691188.aspx

You can use any of the following commands to list out the replicas.

```
Get-PublicFolder -recurse \non_ipm_subtree |fl name, replicas
Get-PublicFolderStatistics | fl
Get-PublicFolderStatistics –Server ExchangeServerName
```